# Jquery mouseover not working

Tags: jquery, mouseover

The problem is that I only get `span` element showed when I click on  `li` not when I hover over `li`!

I have something like:

```
       <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
        @foreach (var category in Model.Categories)  
     {
        <li class="categoryListEl"><a>@category.Name <span      style="float:right;display:none"class="badge badge-important">
<button class="close">&times;</button></span></a></li>
     }
         </ul>
```

My Jquery code is:

```
 $(function ()
    {
  $(".categoryListEl").mouseover(function () {
           $this = $(this);
          $this.find("span").css("display", "block");
    });
    $(".categoryListEl").mouseleave(function ()
    {
        $this = $(this);
        $this.find("span").hide();

    });;
 );
```

Comment: `when I click on li not when I hover on li!`...click ??? where is your click function ??

Comment: Might be useful if you put a working version in http://jsfiddle.net/ for people to, well, fiddle with

Comment: @bipen Nowhere, this is why it's strange behaviour. I get span showed only when I click on li. It is expected to span be showed when I hover over li.

Comment: WEIRD!!!! make sure you are not manupilating this element nowhere else in your code... the codes looks fine for me...

Comment: Hey @VladoPandžić, did your problem solved?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
    $(function ()
        {
      $(".categoryListEl").mouseenter(function () {
               $this = $(this);
              $this.find("span").css("display", "block");
        }).mouseleave(function ()
        {
            $this = $(this);
            $this.find("span").hide();

        });
});
```

Comment: same problem happening to me but your solution doesn't solve it.

Answer (score 1):

There's some of syntax error in your code. You might try this code, which always works:

```
$(function () {
    $(".categoryListEl").hover(function () {
        $(this).find("span").toggle();
    });
});
```

[**FIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/TPQTq/)

Comment: In fact, I see now were the problem was. Code works only if the F12 developer console is closed. I had it opened.

Comment: Cool. Finally you got the solution!